# Copying/serializing the object hierarchy during debugging in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I am connected to a remote debugging session. I would like to dump/copy the variable whole object hierarchy during debugging. In the previous versions of visual studio, there will be a default option to convert the object hierarchy into xml. The idea for me is to persist the whole object hierarchy in a flat file without doing a remote deployment. I would like to check if there is any out of the box solution in visual studio before using serializers.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the object into file by using the immediate window and than later load it into a temp variable.

If you want to compare the objects recursively, there is an answer I have posted earlier today, by using the Oz Code plugin in VS
[Compare 2 object of the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858359/compare-2-object-of-the-same-class/31861289#31861289)

If you want to serialize the object between sessions, you can also do this with Oz Code by using the Compare -> save feature and it wil be available between the debugging sessions:

[image]