# Compare 2 object of the same class

Tags: c#, compare

Recently, I ran into a problem of comparing 2 objects of the same class in C#. I need to know which fields/properties are changed.

Here is the example:

```
SampleClass 
{
  string sampleField1;
  int sampleField2;
  CustomClass sampleField3; 
}
```

And I have 2 `SampleClass` object, `object1` and `object2`, for example.
These 2 objects have some different field value.

- Can anyone know the best approach to get which fields are different?
- And how to get the (string) names of that different fields/properties?
- I heard of Reflection in .Net. Is that the best approach in this situation?
- And if we didn't have the CustomClass field? (I just make this field for a more general approach, that field does not exist in my case)

Comment: In the general case: there are ways to do this via reflection or meta-programming, but nothing is inbuilt

Comment: that's a strange requirement. Well, why can't you do like `if(object1.sampleField1 != object2.sampleField1) { ... }`?

Comment: Thank you for your information @Marc Gravell : )

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I need to get the string name of the value differed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want Generic way to get all changed properties

you can use this method (and it is using reflection ^_^ )

```
    public List<string> GetChangedProperties(object obj1, object obj2)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        if(obj1 == null || obj2 == null )
            // just return empty result
            return result;

        if (obj1.GetType() != obj2.GetType())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Two objects should be from the same type");

        Type objectType = obj1.GetType();
          // check if the objects are primitive types
        if (objectType.IsPrimitive || objectType == typeof(Decimal) || objectType == typeof(String) )
            {
                // here we shouldn't get properties because its just   primitive :)
                if (!object.Equals(obj1, obj2))
                    result.Add("Value");
                return result;
            }

        var properties = objectType.GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (!object.Equals(property.GetValue(obj1), property.GetValue(obj2)))
            {
                result.Add(property.Name);
            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Please note that this method only gets [Primitive type properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900(v=vs.71).aspx) that have changed and reference type properties that refer to the same instance

**EDIT:** Added validation in case if `obj1` or `obj2` is primitive type (int,string ... ) because I tried to pass string object and it will give an error
also fixed bug of checking whether the two values are `equal`

Comment: I think you should test the type before the value for more safety

Comment: Thank you for your very clean and easy-to-understand answer @Bakri Bitar, and I really like the way you used emotion ^_^ 
I am out of work right now, tomorrow I will try it your way. It looks like a promising solution.
Thank you again,

Comment: I actually don't think this works for anything other than string type properties.

Comment: This should work with any value type and any class implemanting Equals

Comment: @Paradise228 No because `GetValue` returns an object so any primitive type doesn't refer to the same object. Strings work because of how they work.

Comment: @Paradise228 Just to clarify, here is the code running versus my answer http://ideone.com/FMd38U

Answer (score 3):

A slight modification of another answer posted here, but this one works with properties that are not `string` types, doesn't use an internal list and does automatic some preliminary type checking as it's generic:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ChangedFields<T>(T first, T second)
{
    if (obj1.GetType() != obj2.GetType())
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Objects should be of the same type");

    var properties = first
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if(!object.Equals(property.GetValue(first), property.GetValue(second)))
        {
            yield return property.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidG

Answer (score 2):

If you need to compare two objects as part of your business logic reflection is the way to go, unless of course you can write comparator classes for each type.

If you want to compare two objects at run time during debugging, there is a neat plugin called Oz Code that can do that for you, something like this:

[image]